# Run xunit tests with some trait

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a VSTS build that runs Xunit tests in a "Visual Studio Test" task. This works fine when I run all tests.

However, I want to run only tests with a particular trait.

I have tried entering the value "Category=UnitTest" into the "Test Filter criteria" field in the task, but doing so produces a build error:

```
    Error: [xUnit.net 00:00:12.9299360] N1.Common.Testing: Exception discovering tests: No tests matched the filter because it contains one or more properties that are not valid (Category). Specify filter expression containing valid properties (DisplayName, FullyQualifiedName) and try again.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having trouble with this as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work now.

I've added "Category=CI" to the TFS "Visual Studio Test" Task as a Filter.
I had to add a "Dummy" Category, and a Dummy Class to every xUnit Project.

The Dummy Class is just:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Do not delete. At least one "different" attribute is required that the Test Runner properly filters by attribute.
    /// See https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/610 for details
    /// </summary>

    [Dummy]
    public class DummyTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void DummyForTFSTestRunner()
        { }
    }
```

This then allowed the Test Runner to discover my CI Test(s) properly.
See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/610) for details